# Strange symbols in doom-modeline

Tags: fonts, mode-line

When I first installed doom-modeline I used to get the nice symbols for each mode, for some reason now all I get is:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get proper symbols back?

Comment: Do both `all-the-icons-install-fonts` and `nerd-icons-install-fonts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save your time: download `Symbols Nerd Fonts Mono` from https://www.nerdfonts.com and install it.

---

@seagle0128 :

> This package is able to display icons if `nerd-icons` package and required fonts are installed. Run `M-x nerd-icons-install-fonts` to install the necessary fonts. Please refer to the [installation guide](https://github.com/rainstormstudio/nerd-icons.el#installing-fonts).

> Please go to [Nerd Fonts website](https://www.nerdfonts.com/) and get a Nerd font. After installing the font on your machine, you need to set `nerd-icons-font-family` to match its font name so that the font can be properly used under GUI. If you want Nerd Fonts to work under a terminal, please change your terminal’s font to a Nerd font.
>
> If the Nerd Font you installed does not display correctly (e.g. appear cut off), it is recommended to use `Symbols Nerd Fonts Mono` (Symbols Nerd Font). You can use `M-x nerd-icons-install-fonts` to install `Symbols Nerd Fonts Mono` for you. Note that for Windows you’ll need to manually install the font after you used this function.